# multiple jquery ui dialogs with different themes

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

IHAC that would like two jquery ui dialog boxes each with their own theme from theme roller. I have tried creating the html like this:

```
<div id="popupDialog" title="Information">
    <div id="popupMessage"></div>
</div>
<div id="errorDialog" title="Error" class="error">
    <div id="errorMessage"></div>
</div>
```

Then I have downloaded two themes from theme roller limiting one of them with CSS Scope #errorDialog (I have also tried with .error and adding an 'error' class to my #errorDialog). I have included both theme css'es and created two different js functions to activate either dialog. The problem is that it seems the entire #errorDialog is destroyed upon display including my CSS Scope leaving me with the theme of the first included css.

Have I misunderstood the CSS Scope or what? Can anyone give me some clue to have two different dialogs with different themes?

Thanks in advance!

./CJ

Answer (score 0):

Immediatly after I posted the question I found this answer:

http://filamentgroup.com/lab/using_multiple_jquery_ui_themes_on_a_single_page/#commentNumber3